# How to extract/expand variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, stdtuple

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Base
{
  T1 t1; 
  T2 t2;
};

template <typename...TN>
class Derived
    : public Base< std::tuple<QList<TN...>>,
                   std::tuple<QVector<TN...>> > //does not work
{
};

Derived<int, double> d;
```

- `t1` shall become `std::tuple<QList<int>, QList<double>>`
- `t2` shall become `std::tuple<QVector<int>, QVector<double>>`

I don't know if this is possible in general. Currently I use preprocessor magic for that. But I hoped that variadic template can do that too. So, can I do any recursive things or any similar to extract the template?

Comment: I think `Base< std::tuple<QList<TN>...>, std::tuple<QList<TN>...> >` should work fine - i.e. you just put the `...` at the wrong place (it expands the previous pattern, and you want to have `QList<TN0>, QList<TN1>, and so on` but not `QList<TN0, TN1, and so on >`)

Answer (score 1):

As @dyp says, you expanded the pack in the wrong place. It should be like this:

```
: public Base< std::tuple<QList<TN>...>,
               std::tuple<QVector<TN>...> >
```